I've bumped Flink to version 1.19 and RichParallelSourceFunction is now deprecated. How can I migrate and keep paralelism?
I have this piece of code where I am using the  RichParallelSourceFunction to create a class that implements SourceFuntion interface.
class SourceWithSleep(private val input: List<ByteArray>, private val sleep: Long) :
        RichParallelSourceFunction<ByteArray>() {

        @Volatile
        private var stop = false

        override fun run(ctx: SourceFunction.SourceContext<ByteArray>) {
            input.forEach { ctx.collect(it) }
            Thread.sleep(sleep)
        }

        override fun cancel() {
            stop = true
        }
    }

How can I migrate to use the Source interface, as per Flink documentation BUT keeping the parallelism? I believe that Source does not take that into account.
I tried this:
class SourceWithSleep(
        private val input: List<ByteArray>,
        private val sleep: Long
    ) : Source<ByteArray, SourceSplit, Void> {

        override fun getBoundedness(): Boundedness = Boundedness.BOUNDED

        override fun createReader(
            readerContext: SourceReaderContext
        ): SourceReader<ByteArray, SourceSplit> {
            return SourceWithSleepReader(input.iterator(), sleep)
        }

        override fun createEnumerator(
            enumeratorContext: SplitEnumeratorContext<SourceSplit>
        ): SplitEnumerator<SourceSplit, Void> {
            return SimpleSplitEnumerator()
        }

        override fun restoreEnumerator(
            enumeratorContext: SplitEnumeratorContext<SourceSplit>,
            checkpoint: Void?
        ): SplitEnumerator<SourceSplit, Void> {
            return SimpleSplitEnumerator()
        }

        override fun getSplitSerializer(): SimpleVersionedSerializer<SourceSplit> {
            return SplitSerializer()
        }

        override fun getEnumeratorCheckpointSerializer(): SimpleVersionedSerializer<Void> {
            return VoidSerializer()
        }
    }

    class SourceWithSleepReader(
        private val inputIterator: Iterator<ByteArray>,
        private val sleep: Long
    ) : SourceReader<ByteArray, SourceSplit> {
        
        override fun start() {}

        override fun pollNext(output: ReaderOutput<ByteArray>?): InputStatus {
            if (stop) return InputStatus.END_OF_INPUT

            if (inputIterator.hasNext()) {
                output?.collect(inputIterator.next())
                Thread.sleep(sleep)
                return InputStatus.MORE_AVAILABLE
            }

            return InputStatus.END_OF_INPUT
        }

        override fun snapshotState(checkpointId: Long): List<SourceSplit> {
            return emptyList()
        }

        override fun isAvailable(): CompletableFuture<Void> {
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null)

        override fun notifyNoMoreSplits() {}
        override fun addSplits(splits: MutableList<SourceSplit>?) {}
        override fun close() {

        class SimpleSplitEnumerator : SplitEnumerator<SourceSplit, Void> {
        override fun start() {}
        override fun handleSplitRequest(subtaskId: Int, requesterHostname: String?) {}
        override fun addSplitsBack(splits: List<SourceSplit>, subtaskId: Int) {}
        override fun addReader(readerId: Int) {}
        override fun snapshotState(checkpointId: Long): Void? = null
        override fun close() {}
    }

    class SplitSerializer: SimpleVersionedSerializer<SourceSplit> {
        override fun getVersion(): Int = 1
        override fun serialize(split: SourceSplit?): ByteArray {
            return split.toString().toByteArray()
        }
        override fun deserialize(version: Int, serialized: ByteArray?): SourceSplit? {
            throw UnsupportedOperationException("No splits expected.")
        }
    }

    class VoidSerializer: SimpleVersionedSerializer<Void> {
        override fun getVersion(): Int = 1
        override fun serialize(split: Void?): ByteArray {
            return split.toString().toByteArray()
        }
        override fun deserialize(version: Int, serialized: ByteArray?): Void? {
            throw UnsupportedOperationException("No splits expected.")
        }
    }


However I am having issues in understanding if parallelism is being assured with this solution. I am very new to Flink and just off documentation I'm having issues understanding this.

Flink 1.9, or 1.19?

sorry. 1.19 is the correct version.

When the new Source interface's createReader() method is called, it gets passed a SourceReaderContext that provides details about parallelism and the instance being called (its subtask index). That should provide you with the information required to implement a proper parallel source function.

The new Source interface can be daunting at first. An alternative is to use the DataGen connector followed by a map implements the logic you're porting over from your RichParallelSourceFunction.
